# String comparison in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I've currently got a webserver set up which I communicate over SOAP with my iPhone app. I am returning a `NSString` containing a GUID and when I attempt to compare this with another `NSString` I get some strange results.

Why would this not fire? Surely the two strings are a match?

```
NSString *myString = @"hello world";

if (myString == @"hello world")
    return;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703554/understanding-nsstring-comparison Nicely answered here as well.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Use the `-isEqualToString:` method to compare the value of two strings. Using the C `==` operator will simply compare the addresses of the objects.

```
if ([category isEqualToString:@"Some String"])
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Comment: AH! Thanking you muchly. Feel like a bit of a fool on this one!

Comment: My guess is that in ObjectiveC++ you could create an operator overload to give you syntactically-sugary ability to use == but no sane objective C programmer would do this, because == is only used for identity checks in objective C objects.

Answer (score 54):

You can use case-sensitive or case-insensitive comparison, depending what you need.
Case-sensitive is like this:

```
if ([category isEqualToString:@"Some String"])
{
   // Both strings are equal without respect to their case.
}
```

Case-insensitive is like this:

```
if ([category compare:@"Some String" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
{
   // Both strings are equal with respect to their case.
}
```

Comment: I think it should be: 
  ([category compare:@"Some String" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame)

Comment: Be careful with the "compare" function because if the string (in this case "category") is nil, compare will always return NSOrderedSame.

Comment: That's a great point @nh32rg!! +1 for that!  Does the isEqualToString have the same problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can compare string with below functions.

```
NSString *first = @"abc";
NSString *second = @"abc";
NSString *third = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"abc"];
NSLog(@"%d", (second == third))  
NSLog(@"%d", (first == second)); 
NSLog(@"%d", [first isEqualToString:second]); 
NSLog(@"%d", [first isEqualToString:third]); 

Output will be :-
    0
    1
    1
    1
```