# Matching Strings in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a for loop which loops through an array and want to match a search field's text to an object in the array.

I have the following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < [data2 count]; i++) {
    if ([data2 objectAtIndex:i] == searchField.text) {
        NSLog(@"MATCH");
            break;
    }
}
```

I know in Java it can be done by e.g. `if(searchField.text.equalsIgnoreCase(the object to match against))`

How is this done in objective C, to match the string without case?

Also, what if I wanted to match part of the string, would that be done in Obj C char by char or is there a built in function for matching parts of Strings?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty close to: [Understanding NSString comparison in Objective-C ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703554/understanding-nsstring-comparison-in-objective-c), but you want `caseInsensitiveCompare:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your strings are NSStrings, you can find your answers at the [NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

NSString supports [caseInsensitiveCompare:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/caseInsensitiveCompare%3a) and [rangeOfString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3a) or [rangeOfString:options:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3aoptions%3a) if you want a case insensitive search.

The code would look like this:

```
if (NSOrderedSame == [searchField.text caseInsensitiveCompare:[data2 objectAtIndex:i]) {
    // Do work here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[[data2 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString: searchField.text]
```

Comment: This comparison would be case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You use `isEqual:` (to compare objects in general) or `isEqualToString:` (for NSStrings specifically). And you can get substrings with the `substringWithRange:` method.