# Why the NSString and string returned by JSON are not equal although both contain the same value

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, encoding, nsstring

When I assign the value to the bank:  `banca.name = @"CheBanca!";` the following condition returns true.

```
if(banca.name==@"CheBanca!"){
        header.bankNameLabel.textColor=[UIColor greenColor];
}
```

But when I assign the same value as:  `banca.name = [jsonBanca objectForKey:@"nome_banca"];` the condition return false although    `NSLog(@"Bank name: %@", [jsonBanca objectForKey:@"nome_banca"]);` outputs the value `Bank name: CheBanca!`

The following code shows how I get jsonBanca:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[responseData release];

NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue];
[responseString release]; 

NSArray *jsonBanche = [results objectForKey:@"banche"];
NSLog(@"%@",jsonBanche);
NSMutableArray  *banks = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:jsonBanche.count];

for (int i=0; i<jsonBanche.count; ++i) {

        NSDictionary *jsonBanca = [jsonBanche objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

This code `NSLog(@"%@",jsonBanche);` returns the banks:

```
{
    "nome_banca" = "CheBanca!";
    "nome_prodotto" = "Conto Deposito";
    rating = "A-1";
}, ...
```

The question is why this two strings @"CheBanca!" and the string recieved by JSON are not equal although they contain the same phrase. And how to make them equal to return true in the condition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If "a == b" is false when comparing two NSString objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598599/if-a-b-is-false-when-comparing-two-nsstring-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare strings accurately, you should use the `isEqualToString` method.

```
if ([banca.name isEqualToString:@"CheBanca!"]) {
   // strings match
   header.bankNameLabel.textColor=[UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To check for equality between two strings, use `isEqualToString:`

```
if ([banca.name isEqualToString:@"CheBanca!"]){
    header.bankNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Your previous code (`if (banca.name == @"CheBanca!") {`) was only checking for equality of the pointer's address.

Get more details about the `NSString` class [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `NSString*` is a pointer to a `NSString`, as they are loaded through separate ways they are two different `NSString`s and have two different addresses. == compares the addresses and so sees them as different.

To compare the values of the string use the [compare:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) and related methods of `NSString` or the [isEqualToString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) method

Comment: The use of compare: is overkill when just checking for equality.