# "if" statement for two NSString values is not working

Tags: ios, if-statement, nsstring, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If “a == b” is false when comparing two NSString objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598599/if-a-b-is-false-when-comparing-two-nsstring-objects)

In an "if" statement I'm comparing two strings, "currentDateString" and "dateCreatedString", to get "Today" if true and "dateCreatedString" if false.  Although they should be equal when creating a new item, the if statement is returning false every time and just giving the currentDateString when I'm looking to get "today".

```
- (NSString *)dateCreatedString
{
// Create a NSDateFormatter that will turn a date into a simple date string
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
NSString *dateCreatedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[_detailItem dateCreated]];
return dateCreatedString;
}
- (NSString *)currentDateString
{
// Create a NSDateFormatter that will turn a date into a simple date string
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
NSString *currentDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
return currentDateString;
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
//places "Today" in the dateLabel if the two strings both equal today
if ([self currentDateString] == [self dateCreatedString] || [_detailItem dateCreated] == nil) {
    [_dateTxt setText:@"Today"];
}
else{
    [_dateTxt setText:[self dateCreatedString]];
}
}
```

**Could somebody help explain why this is happening, and how to fix it?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `isEqualToString` to compare strings like this:

```
if ([[self currentDateString] isEqualToString:[self dateCreatedString]])
```

Using `==` you are comparing the pointers to the string objects, which certainly are not the same.

Comment: Thank you for the timely and detailed response, sir.  It works.