# Compare two strings in obj-c

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If “a == b” is false when comparing two NSString objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598599/if-a-b-is-false-when-comparing-two-nsstring-objects)

Simple Question of comparing 2 strings:

```
if (string1 == string2)
{
    NSLog(@"it is equal!");
}
```

thats it but it wont work for me it is always `!=` 
i testet it with `string2 = string1;` but it wont work.

so i tested `if (string1 isEqualToString:string2)` but in that case there is a syntax error

Thanks for any help!

Regards Curtis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` compares the address of the objects, not their content. Two different objects will obviously never have the same address.

To compare strings use `NSString`'s `isEqualToString:` method:

```
if ([string1 isEqualToString:string2]) {
    NSLog(@"it is equal");
}
```

Note the square brackets `[ ]`. This is the proper Objective-C syntax for sending messages (i.e. calling functions).

To generally compare object in regards to their content, use `isEqual:`.

Comment: Member for 2.5 years, and you've never seen this duplicate before?

Comment: @jrturton He was missing the `[ ]`. If anything, I'd consider this "too localized", rather then a duplicate.

Comment: you saved my day iam really new to Obj-c. I found so many answers to my coding problems and again I love the Community!

Answer (score 1):

Use `if ([url isEqualToString:turl])`. It is the correct syntax, with the [] you mark that you are sending a message to the object.