# Why isn't my String comparison working in iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding NSString comparison in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703554/understanding-nsstring-comparison-in-objective-c)

I've used this simple code for several releases of an app, and until iOS 6 the string comparison has worked but now it fails -Why?

```
if(selectedCell.textLabel.text==@"Font"){
    NSLog(@"going to dofontpicker");
    [self doFontPicker];
}else if(selectedCell.textLabel.text==@"Color"){
    NSLog(@"going to do colorpicker");
    [self doColorPicker];
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would have ever worked in any version of iOS...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it never really worked. Comparing strings doesn't work using the `==` operator, since strings (NSString objects) are pointers - doing a numerical comparison only compares their address, not their contents. You need to write

```
if ([someString isEqualToString:@"Font"]) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Edit: I hear you screaming "But it worked! It really worked until iOS 6!" - Nope. It didn't, it was just something accidental.

Comment: You're right - I'm an idiot and I do it correctly in other places...thanks

Comment: @wayneh, lol its nice that you admitted. Now delete this question before your question rating goes further in free fall.