# Equal strings not equal?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding NSString comparison in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703554/understanding-nsstring-comparison-in-objective-c)

I'v encountered strange things in objective-c, I'm trying to compare cell.label with elements title which is string. to identify whever it is a cell I am looking for.

```
NSLog(@"%@", cell.textLabel.text);
NSLog(@"%@", [_dropDownSelection1.elements[1] title]);
if(cell.textLabel.text == [_dropDownSelection1.elements[1] title]){
    NSLog(@"Positive");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Negative");
}
```

NSLog prints that the text in both is exactly the same, but still i always end up with negative... Why is that?

Comment: try using this format `[foo isEqualToString:bar]` for string comparison since yu are comparing the text itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `[cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:[_dropDownSelection1.elements[1] title]]` to compare the strings.

Comment: strange. tried this way also. But still the result is the same.. NSLog prints both values the same, but comparison gets negative

Comment: Could you show us what does the NSLog print?

Comment: Everything works now, just added my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing pointers with one another, not the strings.

Use IsEqual instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare them like that.

See the section Identifying and comparing strings on the [Objective-C docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which worked for me! I don't know why but, without initializing variables i couldn't get it work, even using isEqualToString as provided above.

```
NSLog(@"CELL:%@", cell.textLabel.text);
NSLog(@"ELEM:%@", [_dropDownSelection1.elements[1] title]);
NSString *labl = cell.textLabel.text;
NSString *tit = [_dropDownSelection1.elements[1] title];

if([labl isEqualToString:tit])
{

    NSLog(@"Positive");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Negative");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method for compare two strings is isEqualToString:

Your code is like this

```
NSLog(@"%@", cell.textLabel.text);
NSLog(@"%@", [_dropDownSelection1.elements[1] title]);

if(cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:[_dropDownSelection1.elements[1] title])
{
NSLog(@"Positive");
}
else
{
NSLog(@"Negative");
}
```