# Objective-C Basics: Creating a Function with String

Tags: objective-c

I'm very new to Objective-C.  I've developed several dozens of desktop applications with VB.NET and several dozens more with REAL Stupid for Macs.  I've read several hard-cover books and PDF books over Objective-C functions.  They only talk about how to create a function with integers.  I want to go beyond integers.  For example, the following simple VB.NET function involves a string, returning true or false (boolean).  It's quite simple and straightforward.

```
Function SayBoolean (ByVal w As String) As Boolean
If w = "hello" Then
    Return True
Else
    Return False
End if
End Function
```

The following function returns a string (the file extension) with a string (a file path).

```
Function xGetExt(ByVal f As String) As String
    'Getting the file extension    
    Dim fName1 As String = Path.GetFileName(f)
    Dim fName2 As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)
    Dim s As String = Replace(Replace(fName1, fName2, ""), ".", "")
    Return s
End Function
```

So how do you specify string parameters and return a boolean or a string in creating a function with Objective-C?  Objective-C is terribly difficult for me so far.

Thank you for your help.

Tom

Comment: I am not sure what books you've read that only cover passing integers, but they sound terrible. You should find more than enough resources here https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 1

```
//The return value is a boolean (BOOL)
- (BOOL)sayBoolean:(NSString*)w //w is the string parameter
{
    //Use isEqualToString: to compare strings
    return [w isEqualToString:@"hello"]; 
}
```

Example 2

```
//The return value is a string
- (NSString*)xGetExt:(NSString*)f
{
   //pathExtension exists as an NSString method in a category
   // and returns a string already.
   return [f pathExtension]; 
}
```

---

Why you need to use `isEqualToString:` [Understanding NSString comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703554/understanding-nsstring-comparison-in-objective-c)

Comment: How do you use the string you've specified with the If loop like

    If w = "hello" Then

    End if

If I write

    If (w == @"hello"){

    }

I get an error.

Thank you,

Comment: It returns a BOOL so there is no reason for an `if` statement. If you want an if statement then it would be `if([w isEqualToString:@"hello"])return YES;else return NO;`