# How to compare coredata string and NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding NSString comparison in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703554/understanding-nsstring-comparison-in-objective-c)

Header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *pid;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
```

Coredata NSString stored:

```
[newPref setValue: @"0" forKey:@"pid"];  //correctly show in DB & NSLog
[newPref setValue: @"Sales" forKey:@"name"];
```

After later retrieving, evaluation fails:

```
if(preference.pid == @"0")
```

Debugger says:

```
_pid = (NSSting *) 0x... @"o\xee\"
_name = (NSString *) )x0.. @<variable is not NSString>
```

Is my storing of the NSString incorrect, or is my evaluation wrong?
Note: The Coredata model is type string also.

Comment: Its hard to say if you might have an error somewhere else. But you should generally compare strings with isEqualToString:

Comment: By 'Header file:' do you mean your NSManagedObject class? It should not contain @property values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703554/understanding-nsstring-comparison-in-objective-c

Comment: @TheJer Why wouldn't NSManagedObject classes contain property values? It's perfectly reasonable/expected for them to have many.

Comment: @MechIntel Whoops, I was thinking of synthesize vs dynamic and for some reason was thinking they were declared as dynamic in the .h file also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are comparing the *objects*, but if you want to compare strings, it should be

```
if ([preference.pid isEqualToString:@"0"])
```