# How do i get segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass: x, to recognize the destination class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get a simple `NSLog` message if the `destinationviewcontroller` `isKindOfClass` like this:

*FirstViewController.m*

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]]) {

        NSLog(@"The destinationViewController isKindOfClass SecondViewController");
}
```

Within the storyboard i have ctrl+dragged from a bar button item in the `FirstViewController` to the `SecondViewController` and chosen modal segue.
I've also made sure to `#import` the `SecondViewController.h` in `FirstViewContrller.m` and i have given the `SecondViewController` the "custom class" of `SecondViewController` in the identity inspector.

Do i need to add/do something else, because I'm not getting the `NSLog` message at this point.

Edit: I forgot to inform that i did in fact embed the secondViewController in a navigationViewController.

Comment: Try logging destinationViewController - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@“%@“,segue.destinationViewController
);
}

Comment: Hm, does one really know the class of the destination segue controller at that point at all? Isn't that per se a NSViewController and usually is cast to the actual controller?

Comment: Are you sure you weren't embed your ViewController in Navigation controller?

Comment: @Szu You are right! I did embed it in a navigation controller. Guessing that's why it won't work then? But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destionationViewController;

    if ([navigationController.viewControllers[0] isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]]) {

        NSLog(@"The destinationViewController isKindOfClass SecondViewController");
}
```

But if you want something more generic I would do:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    id dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([dvc isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] && ((UINavigationController *)dvc).viewControllers > 0) {
        dvc = [[dvc viewControllers] firstObject];
    }

    NSLog(@"The destinationViewController is: %@", NSStringFromClass([dvc class]));
}
```

Comment: Since i had my view controller embedded in an Navigation Controller, this works like a charm. I tried my code without embedding the view controller in an navigation controller and then the NSLog message got through. Thank you Szu.

Comment: @getJETsetTER Please look at my updated answer it might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{  
    HomeViewController *edit=[segue destinationViewController];  
    if ([HomeViewController.viewControllers[0] isKindOfClass:[CheckViewController class]])       
    {

             //You are ready for coding here

    }

}
```

Try this code. This might help.

Answer (score -1):

First you would have to set `destinationViewController`

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
       {

             if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifierHere"] )
             {
                  //Now you can assign here the destinationViewController
                SecondViewController *secondController = [segue  destinationViewController];

                   //now you don't need this but if you want you can
                  if([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]])

                  {
                         NSLog(@"The destinationViewController isKindOfClass SecondViewController");
                  }




             }

}
```

You can use `[segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]]`

inside the if statement if you want.But its not needed now you can get the Identifier from your xcode.

Comment: You shouldn't compare strings using == operator. Please look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703554/understanding-nsstring-comparison