# How to check the text of an NSTextField (Label)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nstextfield

In `Xcode` I'm trying to get the text of an `NSTextField` (Label) to see if it says `Yes` or it is says `No`

I've tried this:

```
if ([LabelYesNo StringValue] == @"Yes"){
    [LabelYesNo setStringValue:@"No"];
else{
    [LabelYesNo setStringValue:@"Yes"];
    }
}
```

and

```
if (LabelYesNo isEqualToString @"Yes"){
    [LabelYesNo setStringValue:@"No"];
else{
    [LabelYesNo setStringValue:@"Yes"];
    }
}
```

and a few other variations of that. Just can't seem to get it right.... Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[theTextField stringValue] isEqualToString:@"Yes"];
```

should work

in your first code, you're comparing strings via `==`. Using the C == operator will simply compare the addresses of the objects.

in your second code, your whole code is wrong, and you'are trying to compare element of type `NSTextField` to NSString.

see [String comparison in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592511/string-comparison-in-objective-c)

Comment: Marek, Brilliant - thanks for the answer. I completely understand why it needs to be this way now that you've written it out.