# How can I compare a string variable to a string in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, if-statement, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String comparison in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592511/string-comparison-in-objective-c)

I realize that the question is not very specific. I am working on a simple trivia game to test a couple of things, right now it has 5 arrays, one for the questions, one for the first answer option, one for the second answer option, one for the third, and one that says which one is correct.

I have an if statement in that checks wether the button pressed matches the correct answer.

Answer2 is connected to the button that would select option b in my trivia app, strCorrect is the string array that holds the single character that says which option out of the three is right, intCurrentQuestion is just an integer I use to reference the index of the arrays.

```
-(IBAction)Answer2{
    if ([strCorrect objectAtIndex:intCurrentQuestion] == [NSString stringWithFormat:@"B"]){
        //do these things blah blah
    }
}
```

The problem is that there are no errors when it is compiled but it doesn't work either. How do I go about making this work?

For testing purpose I am cheating and passing the strCorrect to a hidden label in the nib and then comparing the label text to @"B" and it works but its...well its just awful.

Comment: Type the title of this question into Google. The first hit is your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing in your code above is comparing the *memory address* of two strings, not their value. Do compare two NSStrings you have to do this:

```
[[strCorrect objectAtIndex:intCurrentQuestion] isEqualToString:@"B"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[strCorrect objectAtIndex:intCurrentQuestion] isEqualToString:@"B"]
```