# UITableView with UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I have a tableview and I want you to press a certain cell appears alertview with personalized data for each cell.
This is the code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *message=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tableViewData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


if (message == @"Juan") {

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alerta" message:@"Ciudad de México" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cerrar" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];

}

}
```

You see if I press the cell that says Juan see a UIAlertView and if I press another cell appears Pedro UIAlertView and if for each cell but pressing the cell does not appear in alertview I'm wrong I hope I can help and can not find solution from and through .

Comment: still does not work, here the link http://stackoverflow.com/q/11587330/1539443

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String comparison in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592511/string-comparison-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot test strings for equality with ==, so your test `message == @"Juan"` will always fail. Use `[message isEqualToString:@"Juan"]` instead.

Comment: thanks but still I have a doubt because you still can not work as I wish :( here the link http://stackoverflow.com/q/11587330/1539443