# Weird situation with IF statement

Tags: ios, ios7

I have the following code:

```
if (flag == 2 && username1 != username2 && password1 != password2)
{
 alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle: @"INCORRECT...
```

Values I have:

flag = 2 , username1 = @“aa“, password1 = @“aa“, username2 = @“aa“, password2 = @“aa“

So the above IF statement should evaluate to false right? Yet for reasons unbeknownst to me, the statements after the IF statement are executed! Any idea why?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Use parenthesis inside the IF statement to override operator precedence rules

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592511/string-comparison-in-objective-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `username1` and the other strings are just `char *` variables, the *pointers* can be different even though the *content* is the same.

In C, you would use `strcmp` for this but, in ObjC, I think you have to use the `-isEqualToString:` method, something like:

```
if ((flag == 2) &&
    (![username1 isEqualToString:username2]) &&
    (![password1 isEqualToString:password2]))
```

Comment: You were a minute faster - you get my upvote. ;o)

Answer (score 3):

To compare the string content instead of the object, use Equal:

```
if ([string isEqualToString:@"Some String"])
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```