# The code does not reads the if statement

Tags: c

```
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <stdlib.h>
```

what's wrong?

```
   int main()
```

this is the code

```
    {
    char planet;
    char earth;
    int  weight;
    float mass;
    int a=9;
    printf("Planet Name \n");
    scanf("%s",&planet);
```

the compiler does not reads the if statement it just jumps to the else statement

```
    if(planet=earth){

    printf("Enter your weight \n");
    scanf("%d",weight);
    mass=weight/a;
    printf("Your mass is %d",mass);}
    else {
    printf("Aww,snap!!!!!!We couldn't find the data");
    }

    return 0;}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String comparison in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592511/string-comparison-in-objective-c)

Comment: i tried that too earlier but that doesn't work

Comment: My first comment was nonsens, please checkout the duplicate question.

Comment: i tried that to earlier but it doesn't work

Comment: can you just type the code please @sinclair

Comment: @AyushJha How do you want this to work? `planet` is a single char, but you try to put a string into it, which is an issue waiting to happen. And you don't initialise `earth`, so who knows what it contains once the values would be compared (with `==`, not `=` if you're trying to compare single characters, but `strcmp` if you're trying to compare strings).

Comment: There are so many bugs here it's hard to know where to start.  Here are a few:  (1) the `=` operator is assignment, not comparison (2) `earth` is undefined because you never assign to it, so it's value is unpredictable (3) You're only allocating single characters for `planet` and `earth`, so you have memory violations.  You need to change them to arrays. (4) Your `scanf` call that's meant to set `weight` won't work because you aren't passing the address.  Here's what you need to do:  Study a C tutorial and learn the basics of the language, and turn on compiler warnings (and fix them).

Comment: You also need to use `strcmp` to compare strings, not `==`.

Comment: ok i am just a beginner  i know very less about c and this is just my second project and by the way thanks for your help guys

Comment: You might also find the division `weight / a` does not give the result you want because it performs integer division. I suggest `mass = (float)weight / a;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this

```
if(planet=earth){
```

you are doing equivalent to:

```
char x = planet=earth;
if(x){
```

and not

bool x = planet==earth;
   if(x){

the wrong part is that according to the language spacification

```
if(x){
```

can be accepted by the compiler and in case x is not a boolean expression, it will be converted to a boolean one, BUT following the criteria:

- false if x is zero,  true otherwise.

so at the end

```
if(false){ //never met until the char given as input is a valid
    ...
else {
    printf("Aww,snap!!!!!!We couldn't find the data");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You `planet` is a `char` so it can hold only one `char` but in `scanf` you are trying to read string instead.
use `%c` instead of `%s`

`scanf("%c",&planet);`

Variable `earth` contains garbage initially because you haven't assigned any value to it.
In the `if` statement you are assigning `=` instead of comparision `==`.

When you are reading value for `weight` you are not using `address of`operator `&` hence it can't read the value.

`mass=weight/a;` here you should have used explicit typecasting else your result would be in `int` which would be later upgraded to `float` while assigning but your decimal value would already be lost by then.

```
int main()
 {
char planet;
char earth='A'; //at least assign something
int  weight;
float mass;
int a=9;
printf("Planet Name \n");
scanf("%c",&planet);

if(planet==earth){

printf("Enter your weight \n");
scanf("%d",&weight);
mass=(float)weight/a;
printf("Your mass is %d",mass);}
else {
printf("Aww,snap!!!!!!We couldn't find the data");
}

return 0;}
```

I didn't compile, should work.

Comment: Change ```%d``` to  ```%f``` in ```printf("Your mass is %f",mass);``` as it's float. Will work, just compiled

Answer (score 0):

The correct version of your code is this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
 {
char planet;
char earth='e';//Assign a value to this variable first.
int  weight;
float mass;
int a=9;
printf("Planet Name \n");
scanf("%c",&planet);

if(planet==earth){

printf("Enter your weight \n");
scanf("%d",&weight);
mass=(float)weight/a;
printf("Your mass is %f",mass);}
else {
printf("Aww,snap!!!!!!We couldn't find the data");
}

return 0;}
```

If you input 'e' in the console you will get your required answer after you enter the weight.